# Does a carpet made from wool have better acoustic properties than a synthetic carpet?

Tags: sound, materials

[This PDF document](http://www.campaignforwool.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/ACOUSTIC-PERFORMANCE.pdf) is claiming the following:

> Wool carpets may have some
>   advantages over nylon carpets in this respect, particularly for
>   low frequency noise, as is demonstrated in Figure 1.
>   [image]

Is this indeed true? Will 2 carpets that differ only in material (wool vs synthetic fibre) have significant different acoustic properties?

Comment: Your question asks if there is is a "significant" difference, yet the graph seems to show a moderate difference. What would constitute a "significant" difference in your mind?

Comment: @Flimzy potato…po ta to(e). Any difference at all would be "significant".

Comment: @HasH_BrowN: If that's true for the OP, he can state as such. To anyone who studies acoustics, that's absolutely not true.

Comment: Well the nylon is around 90% and the wool is around 96%, so yes that is significant. The fact that graph doesn't show is what type of pile of carpet is being compared, which will make a very significant difference in sound absorption. At work now, so I will add reference later.

Comment: "significant" in my opinion would simply be "if I can hear it".

Comment: @BaGi if significant means you can hear the difference. Then the answer is that it isn't significant difference, unless you have pristine hearing. No reason for me to post any references, since this becomes opinion.

Comment: "If I can hear it" may be a matter of opinion, but "if the average person can hear it" and "what is the perceived difference fo an average person" is quantifiable.

Comment: In the context of a measurement (which this graph appears to represent) "significant" generally has a technical meaning and it isn't 'if I can hear it' or 'well, 96 is bigger than 90', because it depends on the details of the data set and the analysis. Given that the plot shows no error bars there is no way to evaluate the significance of the difference from the plot. Any one have access to the underlying data?